# Extract attributes from methods

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor

Since I am a beginner of Java, I have a lot of questions. For my university, I have to program a fitness app. We have a few tips but most of the code will be created up by us. The formulation of the tasks is a bit squishy and therefore, I have some problems in solving the tasks. But for now, I want to show you, what I have to do. 
I have to set up a class "Fitness-Equipment" with this attributes:

1. name
2. type
3. trained musclegroup (another class)
4. max.trainingduration
5. burned calories per hour

Besides this attributes, there are some methods, I have to implement:

1. constructor
2. int calorieconsumption (int minutes) -> returns calorieconsumption for one trainingsession in the given time (in minutes)
3. int calorieconsumption (int hours, int minutes) -> returns calorieconsumption for one trainingsession in the given time (hours and in minutes)
4. boolean supports(String muscle) -> returns true, if the equipment supports the muscle
5. boolean supports(Musclegroup musclegroup) -> returns true, if equipment supports the musclegroup
6. boolean needspower() -> returns true, if the equipment need power.

I created the class like that:

```
public class Fitness-Equipment {

    private String name;
    private String type;
    private Musclegroupe mousclegroupe;
    private int max.trainingduration;
    private int burnedcaloriesperhour;
    boolean power;

    public Fitness-Equipment(String name, String type, Musclegroupe mousclegroupe, int max.trainingduration, int burnedcaloriesperhour) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.mousclegroupe = mousclegroupe;
        this.max.trainingduration = max.trainingduration;
        this.burnedcaloriesperhour = burnedcaloriesperhour;
    }

    //Setter & Getter for all attributes above//

    public int calorieconsumption (int trainingduration) {
        return (burnedcaloriesperhour =  trainingduration * (burnedcaloriesperhour / 60));
    }

    public boolean supports (String muscle) {
        return (muskelgroupe.contains(muscle));
    }

    public boolean supports (Musclegroupe musclegroupe) {
        return (this.musclegroupe.equals(musclegroupe));
    }

    public boolean needspower () {
        return (power = true);
    }

}
```

Is this right how I implemented it? Sometimes I am not sure, whether I have to add some attributes to my class, or if the methods will do that for me. The biggest problem is, that the tasks are not well formulated and so I am very insecure in solving them. And sorry for my English, it is not my native language and the code was written in German, so I had to translate it :D

Comment: Have you already tried to compile your code?

Comment: Stackoverflow questions asking for advice on "how to proceed" and if your code "is good" or not, is going to earn you negative reputation.  You're getting a pass for now because you're obviously new.  I suggest you read the stackoverflow how-to-ask page before your reputation goes into the negative.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then I would say that you are on the right track.  (But please see below for some feedback about your code.)

*attributes* are for things where the value of the data matters to the nature of the object

*methods* are for things where the operation / algorithm / logic matters to the nature of the object

Attributes only have meaning once they are assigned a specific value, generally at the time of object instantiation.  (But, that value can certainly change over the lifetime of the instantiated object.)  Methods are fully defined before object instantiation (i.e., they are defined for a class), and do not change.  (Although, their exact output and effects can of course vary based on varying inputs.)

So, using your class as an example, something like `burnedcaloriesperhour` is appropriate as an attribute, since it's part of what defines a *particular* piece of fitness equipment, and something like `calorieconsumption()` is appropriate as a method, because the logic for calculating that is unchanging, and is the same for all pieces of fitness equipment.

There is a lot of nuance to this.  Some attributes change rapidly; some attributes are undefined at object instantiation and only take on a value after this or that method is called; class *constants* are like attributes, but have the same value for all objects of that class; and much, much more.  But part of your learning Java will be gaining an ever-expanding conceptual context for understanding these nuances.

I do want to point out a few things about your code:

1. I don't think `max.trainingduration;` will work the way I think you want it to.  That says "the attribute 'trainingduration' that belongs to the object named 'max'.  I think you want `maxTrainingduration` or something like that.
2. The code `return (power = true);` will (a) set `power` equal to `true`, and (b) always return `true`.  I think you mean `return (power == true);`
3. The code `return (burnedcaloriesperhour =  trainingduration * (burnedcaloriesperhour / 60));` changes the value of `burnedcaloriesperhour` every time it is called;  what I think you want is to just return the calculation `trainingduration * (burnedcaloriesperhour / 60)`.
4. It's not clear to me if your code comment `//Setter & Getter for all attributes above//` is a stand-in for setter and getter methods that are not shown, or if it is meant to identify the methods below it as setter and getter methods.  If it's a stand-in for methods not shown, that's fine.  If it's a comment about the methods below it, I want to point out that they are not actually setter and getter methods.

I hope I've answered your question and provided some confidence to you for moving forward.  The best way to gain in confidence and deepen your understanding is to experiment.  Start small; compile-run-fix until you have something working; make small incremental improvements; add output lines to see what is happening and where it is happening; take time to try out what-if scenarios; and repeat this cycle over and over.  You will gain a firm grasp on class structure, and the role of attributes and methods.

Viel Erfolg!

Comment: The Getter & Setter line only declares, that I  created them there, but I didnt want to write the whole code for that here in Stackoverflow. And yes, your tipps and the tipps of everyone else helped me a Lot! It really is like everyone says -> learning by doing :)